# AnalysisException Found duplicate columns in the data schema

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am running PySpark in Jupyter Notebook, trying to load a lot of big JSON files. I've previously tested the same script with only one file (11 GB in size) and it worked without any issue.

My Python script:

```
import os, sys, pandas, time
import findspark
findspark.init('/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2')
import pyspark
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = "/opt/cloudera/Anaconda3/bin/python"

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, StorageLevel
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession, HiveContext, SQLContext

target_directory = "removed for this post"
top_directory = "removed for this post"

sc_conf = SparkConf()
sc_conf.setAppName("test"),
sc_conf.set('spark.ui.port', 49051)
sc_conf.set('spark.executor.memory', '18g'),
sc_conf.set('spark.executor.cores', '4')
sc_conf.set('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-XX:+UseG1GC'),
sc_conf.set('spark.driver.memory', '18g'),
sc_conf.set('spark.yarn.am.memory', '8g'),
sc_conf.set('spark.yarn.am.cores', '4'),
sc_conf.set('spark.task.cpus','1'),
sc_conf.set('spark.serializer','org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer'),

ses = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .config(conf=sc_conf)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
)

sc = ses.sparkContext
start_time = time.time()
sqlContext = HiveContext(ses)

print("LOADING JSON DF")
start_time_json = time.time()
jsonDF = sqlContext.read.json(top_directory + "traceroute*")
print("SUCCESS")
print("Time elapsed: " + str(time.time() - start_time_json) + " seconds")

print("\n")
jsonDF.printSchema()
jsonDF.show(3)

ses.sql("USE my_table_name")
start_time_orc = time.time()
print("WRITING ORC")
#jsonDF.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("main_orc.json")
jsonDF.write.orc("../traceroute_orc")
print("SUCCESS")
print("Time elapsed: " + str(time.time() - start_time_orc) + " seconds")
#print(time.time() - start_time_orc) 
print("\n")

start_time_parquet = time.time()
print("WRITING PARQUET")
jsonDF.write.parquet("../traceroute_parquet")
print("SUCCESS")
print("Time elapsed: " + str(time.time() - start_time_parquet) + " seconds")  
print("\n")
print("Total time elapsed: " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " seconds") 

sc.stop()
```

Then I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    321             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o6192.json.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema: `result`, `lts`, `paris_id`;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnNameDuplication(SchemaUtils.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnNameDuplication(SchemaUtils.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:397)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-99870ac0546e> in <module>()
     67 print("LOADING JSON DF")
     68 start_time_json = time.time()
---> 69 jsonDF = sqlContext.read.json(top_directory + "traceroute*")
     70 print("SUCCESS")
     71 print("Time elapsed: " + str(time.time() - start_time_json) + " seconds")

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in json(self, path, schema, primitivesAsString, prefersDecimal, allowComments, allowUnquotedFieldNames, allowSingleQuotes, allowNumericLeadingZero, allowBackslashEscapingAnyCharacter, mode, columnNameOfCorruptRecord, dateFormat, timestampFormat, multiLine, allowUnquotedControlChars)
    259             path = [path]
    260         if type(path) == list:
--> 261             return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    262         elif isinstance(path, RDD):
    263             def func(iterator):

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1158         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1159         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1161 
   1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
     68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: 'Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema: `result`, `lts`, `paris_id`;'
```

Here is the JSON schema of one object: https://pastebin.com/W6nHuJuL

Why does it say there is duplicates in those columns? As you can see from the JSON I posted, there is no duplicate.

Comment: I successfully loaded the above mentioned without any problem. Did you also try with ´spark.read.option('multiline', True).json(file_name)´ ? Or, may be you are getting unexpected files because you are polling with a '*' at the end of the file name - ´top_directory + "traceroute*´

Comment: It could be the case. I do suspect some file(s) to have something weird about them. Currently loading only 30 or so JSON files at a time (out of the 500 I have) to see which one is the issue. What does the ``spark.read.option`` you suggested do?

Comment: Please refer to https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-json.html

Comment: @Gladiator after changing the line to ``jsonDF = sqlContext.read.option("multiline", "true").json(top_directory + "traceroute*")`` it seems that it now works, but it won't retrieve all the files in the directory that start with traceroute? it only takes one

Comment: You mean to say, now, you are now NOT getting all files from a directory?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to load every file like before, but without the error of course.

Comment: It seems to take only the first JSON object from the first JSON file

Comment: `option` has no relation to the files to be loaded. Please check separately if the wildcard fetched all files names if you wanted.

Comment: I did not modify anything else in the code

Comment: I have a similar issue into Scala code, the issue was that there were files that duplicate the information into the schema, 2 files with the same values, but I am trying to search a way to enable json to read the duplicated files

Comment: I did the exact same thing: added the multilLine=True and it worked, except it only loaded in 1 row of my 103,000+ row JSON file... it also dropped my second nested JSON for some reason... it handled the first one beautifully though!