# Found duplicate column in one of the json when running spark.read.json even though there are no duplicate columns

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I am getting very strange error in PySpark and also in Synapse data flow.

I am reading JSON file with below query but getting duplicate column error **even though there is no duplicate column**. I can read it using other tools and JSON validator and also with data flow but not in PySpark.

PySpark query is as below:

```py
df = (
    spark.read.option("multiline", "true")
    .options(encoding="UTF-8")
    .load(
        "abfss://<Container>]@<DIR>.dfs.core.windows.net/export28.json", format="json"
    )
)
```

This is stacktrace I get:

> AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema: `amendationcommentkey`, `amendationreasonkey`, `amendationregulatoryproofkey`
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 204, in load
> return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
>
> File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in **call**
> return_value = get_return_value(
>
> File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
> raise converted from None
>
> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema: `amendationcommentkey`, `amendationreasonkey`, `amendationregulatoryproofkey`

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that if we have any duplicate names in top level columns as well in nested structure.

Below is the statement from [Apache Spark website](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/sql-migration-guide.html):

> In Spark 3.1, the Parquet, ORC, Avro and JSON datasources throw the exception  `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema`  in read if they detect
> duplicate names in top-level columns as well in nested structures. The
> datasources take into account the SQL config
> `spark.sql.caseSensitive`  while detecting column name duplicates.

Try to use your command as below as everything depends on the schema, as this code successfully helped in my case.

```py
Sch = spark.read.json(schemaPath)
schema = Sch.schema

df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").schema(schema).json(f"{json_path}")
```

Also refer to these SO's( [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385307/remove-duplicate-column-name-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-from-a-json-column-nested-ob), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55515757/analysisexception-found-duplicate-columns-in-the-data-schema), [SO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69985305/duplicate-column-in-json-file-throw-error-when-creating-pyspark-dataframe-databr)). As the authors gave great explanation in different scenarios.

Comment: Did this answer resolve your problem?

Comment: Setting _spark.sql.caseSensitive_ to _true_ helped me.

Comment: @Eyal 100% this solved it for me. Thank you. Better than chatgpt.

Answer (score 1):

```
--Please have this setting before loading--
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: This worked wor me!